# jQuery - Any 2 Checkboxes are mandatorily checked from many

Tags: jquery, checkbox, counter

I have 5 checkboxes and 5 divs... on unchecking on each checkbox I am hiding the relevant div.

But, how can I **STOP** unchecking the checkboxes if count is less than **2** and show a **warning message** `<div class="warning">blablabla</div>`?

Please help me out.

---

### **[Fiddle is Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yd9svd2k/1/)**

---

> **HTML:**

```
<div class="show-hide-items">
    <span class="li-1">Item 1</span>
    <span class="li-2">Item 2</span>
    <span class="li-3">Item 3</span>
    <span class="li-4">Item 4</span>
    <span class="li-5">Item 5</span>
</div>


<div class="warning">Atleast <b>2</b> items are mandatory</div>

<label><input type="checkbox" value="one" checked /> Hide Item 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="two" checked /> Hide Item 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="three" checked /> Hide Item 3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="four" checked /> Hide Item 4</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="five" checked /> Hide Item 5</label>
```

> **jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="one"){$(".li-1").toggle();}
        if($(this).attr("value")=="two"){$(".li-2").toggle();}
        if($(this).attr("value")=="three"){$(".li-3").toggle();}
        if($(this).attr("value")=="four"){$(".li-4").toggle();}
        if($(this).attr("value")=="five"){$(".li-5").toggle();}
    });
});
```

> **CSS:**

```
body{font-family:arial;font-size:13px;}
.show-hide-items{margin-bottom:40px;}
span{display:block;background:#ccc;margin-bottom:5px;padding:10px;}
label{display:block;margin-bottom:5px;}
.warning{display:none;background-color:#f2dede;border:1px solid #ebccd1;color:#a94442;padding:10px;text-align:center;margin-bottom:5px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved in much less code

add a class to the span items, which has same name as value of related checkbox.

```
<span class="one someOtehrClass">Item 1</span>
```

Then, change the click event

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($('input:checked').length <=2){
            $('.warning').show();
            return false;
        }

        $('.warning').hide();
        var item = $(this).val();        
        $('span.'+item).toggle();       
    });
```

See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yd9svd2k/3/).

(Note: JFI The text of you check box says 'Hide' but when it is checked the item is displayed and when it is unchecked the item gets hidden, might need to change the text or initial state of checkbox.)

Comment: Excellent aSharma... Its working like a CHAMP... this is what exactly I want... And thanks for correcting me on Typo :)

Comment: Voted Up for your Smart Answer :) Keep up the Good Work

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length
```

With that you can determine how many checkboxes are checked.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
            return false;
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="one"){$(".li-1").toggle();}
        if($(this).attr("value")=="two"){$(".li-2").toggle();}
        if($(this).attr("value")=="three"){$(".li-3").toggle();}
        if($(this).attr("value")=="four"){$(".li-4").toggle();}
        if($(this).attr("value")=="five"){$(".li-5").toggle();}

        var checked = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
        if(checked.length == 2) {
            $('.warning').show();
            checked.addClass('disabled')
        }else if (checked.length > 2) {
            checked.removeClass('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

UPDATE: Check the updated code.
Basically what I'm doing is adding a class(disabled) to the remaining check boxes and at the beginning of the onclick handler I'm checking if the clicked checkbox has the disable class and if it does I'm escaping the default behavior.

SUGGESTION: Try not to abuse the usage of jquery constructor. Instead try to use reusable variables. For example instead of:

```
$(this).attr('value');
...
$(this).someMethod();
```

use something like this:

```
var $this = $(this)

$this.attr('value');
...
$this.someMethod();
```

That way you wont reconstruct the same variable over and over again. Also every time you do

```
$('some selector');
```

It will look into the dom and that is an expensive operation.

Comment: Hi lexmihaylov, thanks for the reply...

This is what I want exactly... except, 

As I am newbie to jQuery can you please also suggest me that, how can I disable remaining 2 checkboxes?

Comment: Cool... Thanks lexmi... Working great

Answer (score 0):

you can maintain same thing with taking counter variable.

```
var ctr = 5;
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if(ctr <= 2){
            $(".warning").css("display","block");
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="one"){$(".li-1").toggle();}
        if($(this).attr("value")=="two"){$(".li-2").toggle();}
        if($(this).attr("value")=="three"){$(".li-3").toggle();}
        if($(this).attr("value")=="four"){$(".li-4").toggle();}
        if($(this).attr("value")=="five"){$(".li-5").toggle();}
        ctr--;
    });
});
```

Once you have less than or equal to 2 count make div visiable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var click = 0;

$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){

    if(click < 3){
    if($(this).attr("value")=="one"){$(".li-1").toggle();}
    if($(this).attr("value")=="two"){$(".li-2").toggle();}
    if($(this).attr("value")=="three"){$(".li-3").toggle();}
    if($(this).attr("value")=="four"){$(".li-4").toggle();}
    if($(this).attr("value")=="five"){$(".li-5").toggle();}
    }else{
        $(".warning").show();
    }
  click++;
});
```

});

Comment: Shweta, thanks for your quick response... but once items are hidden, if I check the checkbox again, items are not showing :( and also I want to stop checking the last 2 checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Ok Then you can try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
   if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 2){

    if($(this).attr("value")=="one"){$(".li-1").toggle();}
    if($(this).attr("value")=="two"){$(".li-2").toggle();}
    if($(this).attr("value")=="three"){$(".li-3").toggle();}
    if($(this).attr("value")=="four"){$(".li-4").toggle();}
    if($(this).attr("value")=="five"){$(".li-5").toggle();}
    }else{
        $(".warning").show();
    }

});
```

});

Comment: Sorry Swetha... this is also not working :(

I want to disable the remaining 2 checkboxes until user clicks on 3rd checkbox. If more than 2 checkboxes are checked, I want to remove disable behavior for checkboxes and message should be hidden along with

Comment: Can you please share me the Fiddle?